# How to add BID/ASK size to TRADES in a High Frequency Dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, finance

I am working with an intraday trading database. I have a TAQ (Trade and Quote) database, so for each tick I have the date (POSIXct class), the type (BID, ASK, TRADE), the price and the size. I need to add the BID and ASK depth just before the TRADE.

Here is an example database:

```
df = structure(data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(c(rep("2017-12-13 09:15:00", 2), rep("2017-12-13 09:30:00", 2), "2017-12-13 09:31:00", "2017-12-13 09:31:01", 
         rep("2017-12-13 09:32:00", 2), "2017-12-13 09:33:00", rep("2017-12-13 09:35:00", 3), rep("2017-12-13 09:38:00", 4), 
         "2017-12-13 09:40:00", "2017-12-13 09:41:00", "2017-12-13 09:41:05","2017-12-13 09:41:10", "2017-12-13 09:43:00",
         "2017-12-13 09:43:05", "2017-12-13 09:45:00", "2017-12-13 09:45:50", "2017-12-13 09:46:30"), tz=""), 
         type = structure(c("ASK", rep("BID", 2), "TRADE", rep("BID", 3), "ASK", "TRADE", "ASK", "TRADE", "ASK", rep("BID", 2),
         rep("TRADE", 2), "BID", rep("ASK", 3), rep("TRADE", 2), "ASK", "BID", "TRADE"), class = "character"),
         price = structure( c(1915, rep(1905, 3), rep(1910, 2), 1905, 1920, 1910, rep(1915, 3),
         rep(1905, 4), 1910, rep(1920, 5), 1915, 1905, 1910), class = "numeric"), 
         size = structure(c(rep(1000, 3), 2000, rep(1000, 4), 2000, rep(1000, 3), rep(2000, 2), 1000, 1500,
         rep(1000, 8), 2000), class = "numeric")), class = "data.frame")
```

And the expected output is:

```
                  date  type price size BID_size ASK_size
1  2017-12-13 09:15:00   ASK  1915 1000       NA       NA
2  2017-12-13 09:15:00   BID  1905 1000       NA       NA
3  2017-12-13 09:30:00   BID  1905 1000       NA       NA
4  2017-12-13 09:30:00 TRADE  1905 2000     2000     1000
5  2017-12-13 09:31:00   BID  1910 1000       NA       NA
6  2017-12-13 09:31:01   BID  1910 1000       NA       NA
7  2017-12-13 09:32:00   BID  1905 1000       NA       NA
8  2017-12-13 09:32:00   ASK  1920 1000       NA       NA
9  2017-12-13 09:33:00 TRADE  1910 2000     2000     1000
10 2017-12-13 09:35:00   ASK  1915 1000       NA       NA
11 2017-12-13 09:35:00 TRADE  1915 1000     1000     1000
12 2017-12-13 09:35:00   ASK  1915 1000       NA       NA
13 2017-12-13 09:38:00   BID  1905 2000       NA       NA
14 2017-12-13 09:38:00   BID  1905 2000       NA       NA
15 2017-12-13 09:38:00 TRADE  1905 1000     4000     1000
16 2017-12-13 09:38:00 TRADE  1905 1500     3000     1000
17 2017-12-13 09:40:00   BID  1910 1000       NA       NA
18 2017-12-13 09:41:00   ASK  1920 1000       NA       NA
19 2017-12-13 09:41:05   ASK  1920 1000       NA       NA
20 2017-12-13 09:41:10   ASK  1920 1000       NA       NA
21 2017-12-13 09:43:00 TRADE  1920 1000     1000     3000
22 2017-12-13 09:43:05 TRADE  1920 1000     1000     2000
23 2017-12-13 09:45:00   ASK  1915 1000       NA       NA
24 2017-12-13 09:45:50   BID  1905 1000       NA       NA
25 2017-12-13 09:46:30 TRADE  1910 2000     1000     1000
```

I was trying to create an indicator between trades, find the type with the same price as TRADE and sum all rows, finally for the other quote find the best BID/ASK, but my programming skills with POSIXct objects and movements between rows are too basic. I hope that you can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use rolling join in data.table